# How can I stream media files in another monitor (HDMI) using C#?

Tags: c#, media, hdmi

I need to stream/cast media files to another monitor using HDMI, how can I do it? What the way to follow? What library? What can I do?

I'm using C# and I need to show videos and images to another monitor.

I tried to do a jerry-rig solution. I created a form in the 2nd monitor, and send the media files to this form, but this way doesn't show the video, just plays the video audio. How do I play the video?

Code from form1 button:

```
Form1 fr3 = new Form1(); 
fr3.midiaVideo.uiMode = "none"; 
fr3.midiaVideo.enableContextMenu = false; 
fr3.midiaVideo.Visible = true; 
fr3.midiaVideo.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; 
fr3.midiaVideo.URL = @"C:\regency\songs\video\sjjm_T_008_r720P.mp4";
fr3.Controls.Add(fr3.midiaVideo); 
fr3.midiaVideo.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

Comment: This is a very broad question, which usually cannot be answered. Could you please show us, what you already found, what you have tried. Maybe some code to start with? Is the problem steaming media files, or have you got that covered already? You can run an application on a different screen without a problem right? So what is the real problem?

Comment: My problem is how I send the media to another screen. I dont know the way to do it. I tried to do a jerry-jig.. create a Windows Form in the 2nd screen and send the media to this form, but I don't like this way.

Comment: HDMI cast/stream.

Comment: Why don't you like the approach with a Windows Form in the 2nd screen. What do you want differently?

Comment: In the truth, I got all, except a Media Video. I created a Windows Media Player using WMPLib in Form2, and I know how to send the video to this form, but the video doesnt show, only the audio play.

Comment: Form1 button. projetor = form2 > projetor fr3 = new projetor();
            fr3.midiaVideo.uiMode = "none";
            fr3.midiaVideo.enableContextMenu = false;
            fr3.midiaVideo.Visible = true;
            fr3.midiaVideo.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            fr3.midiaVideo.URL = @"C:\regency\songs\video\sjjm_T_008_r720P.mp4";
            fr3.Controls.Add(fr3.midiaVideo);
            fr3.midiaVideo.Ctlcontrols.play();

Comment: instead of posting the comments, could you edit your original post including the details you mention. When doing so, also please figure out what single thing you really want to ask, and phrase you original question towards this one question.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a lot of things (wrong video file, codec issue). I tried your code with a sample file, and got it working with one addition.

What am I seeing is that you code is not showing fr3. So you are adding a control playing a video file, but not visible.

I think you should add the following line:

```
fr3.Show();
```

Remark:
Also, I see that you add a control, while that control is already on the form. Is this really needed?